# Ruby gem facebook_ads exception_with_response: 400 Bad Request

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, rubygems

I'm trying to query the Facebook Marketing API Insights using the facebook_ads Ruby gem. https://github.com/tophatter/facebook-ruby-ads-sdk

I created an app and have Editor permissions on the relevant pages for my company.

Next, I generated a user access token from this [page](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) after selecting ads_management permissions.

Next, I followed the instructions on this [page](https://dev.to/daviducolo/permanent-facebook-page-access-token-3epi) to get a permanent page access token.

With the code below I get this error:

> /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-2.0.2/lib/restclient/abstract_response.rb:223:in `exception_with_response': 400 Bad Request (RestClient::BadRequest)
>       from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-2.0.2/lib/restclient/abstract_response.rb:103:in`return!'
>       from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-2.0.2/lib/restclient/request.rb:809:in `process_result'
>       from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-2.0.2/lib/restclient/request.rb:725:in`block in transmit'
>       from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:853:in `start'
>       from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-2.0.2/lib/restclient/request.rb:715:in`transmit'
>       from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-2.0.2/lib/restclient/request.rb:145:in `execute'
>       from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-2.0.2/lib/restclient/request.rb:52:in`execute'
>       from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-2.0.2/lib/restclient.rb:67:in `get'
>       from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/facebook_ads-0.6.6/lib/facebook_ads/base.rb:15:in`get'
>       from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/facebook_ads-0.6.6/lib/facebook_ads/ad_account.rb:10:in `all'

I have also tried this code with my temporary user access code but get the same result.

Here is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'facebook_ads'

MY_PAGE_PERMANENT_ACCESS_CODE = 'my access code'

APP_SECRET = 'my app secret'

FacebookAds.access_token = MY_PAGE_PERMANENT_ACCESS_CODE

FacebookAds.app_secret = APP_SECRET

accounts = FacebookAds::AdAccount.all
```

Comment: What is the full response that Facebook return to you?

Comment: I edited my question to show the full error response.

Comment: Not the Ruby error. The HTTP response that Facebook sends you. The body should contain an error message.

Comment: Because I have used a gem the response body doesn't seem available to me or I don't know how to get it.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I was using the page permanent access token which was out of scope for the API call. I needed to use my temporary user access code.

> E, [2019-01-19T00:08:49.366067 #19868] ERROR -- : GET /me/adaccounts
>   OAuthException / 100: (#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field
>   (adaccounts) on node type (Page) RestClient::BadRequest: 400 Bad
>   Request

In the pry console for the gem I ran this command to set the account variable:

```
pry(main)> account = FacebookAds::AdAccount.find('act_MY_ACCOUNT_ID')
```

and I get this error:

> E, [2019-01-19T00:12:24.760545 #20188] ERROR -- : GET /me/adaccounts
>   OAuthException / 2635: (#2635) You are calling a deprecated version of
>   the Ads API. Please update to the latest version: v3.2.
>   RestClient::BadRequest: 400 Bad Request

So, I ran this command:

```
pry(main)> FacebookAds.base_uri = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2'
```

> "https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2"

Then `pry(main)> account = FacebookAds::AdAccount.find('act_MY_ACCOUNT_ID')` again.

Finally, I ran:

```
pry(main)> account.ad_insights
```

but the result is an empty array when I know this should not be blank. I'm going to skip the gem and use Ruby net/http to query the API directly.